# smallest difference of a sequence of a list

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am working on program to find the smallest difference of sequence of element.  for example I have a input `A=[7,8,9],M=3`. Difference of all elements of sequence should be in this form S=(|7-7|,|7-8|,|7-9|,|8-7|,|8-8|,|8-9|,|9-7|,|9-8|,|9-9|).`S=[0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,0]`. we get 9 different element in list. So the output of M smallest element of s is 0. since 0 is 3 smallest element. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong

```
enter code here
F=[]
A = [7, 8, 9]
M = 3
S=0
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A)):
        S = S + (abs(A[i] - A[j]))
        t = F.append(S)
        t.sort()
        for k in range(len(t)):
            if k == M:
               break
print(t[k])
```

Comment: According to your implementation, 0 will always the answer because you subtract the elements from themselves as well.

Comment: What should be the output if `S=[0,1,2,1,0,1,2,1,2]` for `M=3`, should it be `[0,0,1]` or should it be `1`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to calculate the difference of each element to itself? This will always be 0. And if `M` is `len(A)` the sum of smallest differences will be 0 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right code is here:

```
A = [7, 8, 9]
M = 3
S=[]   # 
for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A)):
        S.append(abs(A[i] - A[j]))
        #  t = F.append(S)   # t is not defined before

S.sort()
print(S[M-1])  # S is sorted
```

Ask me if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can try this:

```
x=[7,8,9]
y=[abs(j-k) for j in x for k in x]
print(y)
```

What you are doing is basically a nested loop.
Here is how it goes:

```
for i in x:
    for j in x:
       
#==== This is what your program needs =====
i=7
|__j=7
|__j=8
|__j=9
i=8
|__j=7
|__j=8
|__j=9
i=9
|__j=7
|__j=8
|__j=9
```

Now if you print the how it looks like:

```
x=[7,8,9]
for i in x:
    print(f'The main number is {i}.')
    for j in x:
       print(f"{i} - {j} = {abs(i-j)}")
```

And that does exactly what you need

```
The main number is 7.
7 - 7 = 0
7 - 8 = 1
7 - 9 = 2
The main number is 8.
8 - 7 = 1
8 - 8 = 0
8 - 9 = 1
The main number is 9.
9 - 7 = 2
9 - 8 = 1
9 - 9 = 0
```